# disable ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken only for json request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this question have been asked in this forum. but it did not work for me.

my requirement is something like this

```
     if request.type.json?
       #disbale `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`
     else
     # enable `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`
     end
```

any idea !! how to achieve this??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [RDoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) from the most recent Rails version:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

If you find that begins to work, you can restrict when it attaches like this:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, 
    if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

If you are dealing with other formats, you can debug to see which request format you're using in order to disable it.

Answer (score 4):

The [RequestForgeryProtection documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) suggests this to disable CSRF only for JSON.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
end
```